# When I call dynamic fragment from another fragment, I still could access buttons in the first fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments

when 2nd fragment is displayed if a click is made in-where a button in 1st fragment exists(at its position exactly  )- that old button onClick got called, something like a transparent button :), well this should no happen at least with replace() .NOTE: the first fragment is a fragment under TabLayout.

```
public class first_Fragment extends Fragment {

    public first_Fragment ()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
    View rootview=inflater.inflate(R.layout.profile_fragment, container, false);

     final View fragmentContainer = rootview.findViewById(R.id.container);

        Button new_frament_btn= 
        (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.new_frament_btn);
        new_frament_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                 Fragment newFragment = new Second_Fragment();
                  FragmentTransaction transaction =  
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
                transaction.replace(fragmentContainer.getId(), newFragment);
                transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                 transaction.commit();
            }
        });
        Button btn_toast= 
        (Button)rootview.findViewById(R.id.btn1);
        btn_toast.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this is first fragment", 
        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        });
        return rootview;
    }
}
```

the first fragment xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/profile_background_yellow1"
android:id="@+id/container"

android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/new_frament_btn"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_below="@+id/setting"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_friends" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btn1"
            android:layout_width="70dp"
            android:layout_height="70dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:src="@drawable/profile_account_setting"/>
       .............
    />
```

the second fragment code

```
public class Second_Fragment extends Fragment {

    public Second_Fragment ()
    {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_two, container, false);
    }
}
```

the second fragment xml

```
<RelativeLayout   
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff"
  >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:text="second_fragment"
    android:textSize="40dp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. There are many people here that would love to answer your question. However, it is unclear to me what you are asking. Can you please clarify your question? I think you need to provide some more code, but be careful not to provide extra code that is irrelevant to your question. For example, what is the first fragment? What are the buttons that you are trying to access? How are you trying to access the buttons? Do the buttons have `onClick()` callback event handlers?

Comment: i think op means when 2nd fragment is displayed if a click is made -where a button in 1st fragment exists- that old button `onClick` got called, something like a  transparent button :), well tjhis should no happen at least with `replace()` but to be sure plz do as @Code-Apprentice asked and post more code, you might have something wrong, somewhere ...

Comment: yessss @Yazan you are right :) this is the problem i tried to post the code but i couldn't satisfy stackoverflow conditions in post :(

Comment: just edit the question and add the code, then save it, i think this will be ok.

Comment: i posted the code , thx in advance @Yazan

Comment: i am not sure about this, it could be the reason, the place where you add or replace fragments can be called `container` should be an empty holder (an empty linear or frame layout) located in mainactivity XML, so you need to have 3 XMLs 1) for the activity, which have the empty `container` 2) xml of fragment-1, 3) xml of fragment-2, then you either replace/add fragment-1 or fragment-2 in mainActivity's `container`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `android:clickable="true"` in the xml file of second fragment layout. 
I think this is gonna help.

```
<LinearLayout 
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
  android:clickable="true" />
```

Comment: Set clickable property on the second fragment's view to true. The view will catch the event so that it will not be passed to the main fragment. So if the second fragment's view is a layout, this would be the code:
`<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:clickable="true" />`

Comment: thanks – Gaurav Vachhani the answer in comment is the right answer, thx very much :) so edit your answer post to the the right one